# When does a polynomial in two variables form a group?

Tags: group-theory, polynomials

Define an operation $B_n:G \times G \rightarrow G$, where $G \subseteq \mathbb R$, by $B_n(x,y) = \begin{bmatrix}
  1 \\
  x \\
  \vdots \\
  x^n \\
\end{bmatrix}^T 
A 
\begin{bmatrix}
  1 \\
  y \\
  \vdots \\
  y^n \\
\end{bmatrix}$.

I'm trying to determine what matrices $A$ make this a group on some subset of the real numbers (and find what that set is).

For example, $B_1(x,y) = A_{00} + A_{10}x + A_{01}y + A_{11}xy$

The identity is $e = -\frac{(A_{10} - 1)x + A_{00}}{A_{11}x + A_{01}}$, which picks up the restriction on $G$ that $- \frac{A_{01}}{A_{11}} \not\in G$.
Also, since $B_1(x,e) = B_1(e,x)$, we need symmetry: $A_{01} = A_{10}$.

$x^{-1} = - \left( \frac{(A_{10} - 1)x + A_{00}}{(A_{11}x + A_{10})^2} + \frac{A_{10}x + A_{00}}{A_{11}x + A_{10}}\right)$, so there are no new restrictions here (note also I used $A_{01} = A_{10}$).

If $A_{10} = A_{01} = \frac{1}{2}\left(1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 4A_{00}A_{11}}\right)$ and $A_{00}A_{11} \geq -\frac{1}{4}$, it should be associative (I think, and I've not considered expanding into $\mathbb{C}$ yet).

I assume that once we increase $n$ much higher, we run into quintic and higher polynomials, which probably won't be able to be solved. Plus the associativity will be a nightmare to calculate.

We actually have a complicated issue here even when $n = 1$ - when is this closed? Running through the calculations, it's not clear to me that there is a simple answer to that question.

An example of $A$ on $B_1$ that fits the bill is the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$, and that with the set $G = \mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1\}$ forms a group. Identity is $0$, inverse is $-\frac{x}{x-1}$, it's associative, and the only way for $B_1(x,y) = -1$ is for $y = -1$, so it's closed.

How can I generalize this? I only have a bachelor's in math, so there may be some trick theorem that I'm not aware of that could be really useful if applied here. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: @mr_e_man thanks for providing a better description - will update that

Comment: I just found this on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58148/polynomial-group-laws-on-mathbbr2

Comment: @mr_e_man this is excellent. Not very familiar with Lie groups (I'll look into them now!), but that basically says that regardless of n in my post, the set S that forms a group with operation B_n is isomorphic to R\{-1}?

Comment: No, that answer only works for $G=\mathbb R$, I think. The answer by F. Brunault (at least part of it) works for any infinite set $G$, and shows that $B(x,y)=A_{00}+A_{10}x+A_{01}y+A_{11}xy$ and there can't be any higher-degree terms. An essential fact is that for two (single-variable) polynomials $p,q$, if $p(x)=q(x)$ for infinitely many values of $x$, then their coefficients are equal, and $p(x)=q(x)$ for all $x$.

Comment: Got it. This has been very helpful - thank you!!

Comment: It remains to consider the case where $G$ is a finite subset.

Comment: Just to make it clear that this is equivalent to ordinary addition or multiplication (when $G$ is infinite): The identity requirement $x=B(x,e)$ and $y=B(e,y)$ implies $$A_{00}+A_{01}e=0,\quad A_{10}+A_{11}e=1,$$ $$A_{00}+A_{10}e=0,\quad A_{01}+A_{11}e=1$$ and thus $$B(x,y)=(1-A_{11}e)(-e+x+y)+A_{11}xy.$$ Let $z=B(x,y)$. If the coefficient $A_{11}=0$, then this is equivalent to $$(z-e)=(x-e)+(y-e).$$ If $A_{11}\neq0$, then this is equivalent to $$(A_{11}z-A_{11}e+1)=(A_{11}x-A_{11}e+1)\cdot(A_{11}y-A_{11}e+1).$$